# show a progressbar to the use while processing file

Tags: python, bottle

What is the easiest way to show the user a progressbar while a file is processed in a bootle webservice? Is there something build in into bottle?

I have a method for uploading a file on my server and then creating a html page with information about the file. currently when you upload the file it takes about 30s until the html page is shown because my method need some time to generate the page.

it would be nice to show the user a intermediate page with a progress bar.

Comment: Know how to use Ajax ? Create a url in bottle which will show progress bar for example(http://www.ajaxload.info/) and automatically on start it will send ajax request.

Comment: yes i do, so there is no buildin (which i probably had found while reading the docs)

Comment: Bottle isn't so popular framework and maybe there is bulidin solution, but I guess no. The best solution is using Ajax for asynchronous jobs in webdev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm afraid there is no Bottle feature that does this for you.

Part of the reason for that is that a progress bar requires client-side code, and Bottle does not dictate anything about how you use it on the client side.  (Most [micro]frameworks wouldn't.  Just for comparison, [Flask also does not support progress bars natively](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/#upload-progress-bars).)

Have you looked at [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)?  I haven't used it but it looks pretty slick and easy to use.  Perhaps it'll help get your progress bar running smoothly with Bottle?